# Careful proof of set inclusion

Tags: set-theory

Consider the two topologies:

$\tau_{1}=\{\{m\in \mathbb{N}:m<n\}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\tau_{2}=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{N}: 0\in A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$.

I know that the $\tau_1$ topology is contained in the $\tau_2$ topology, because:

\begin{equation}
\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\},\cdots,\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq \tau_2
\end{equation}

I wonder how to prove it with mathematical rigour. Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let $U \in \tau_1$. Then, by definition, either $U = \mathbb{N}$ or $U \in \{ \{m\in \mathbb{N} : m < n\} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Suppose the former. Then clearly $0 \in U$< so $U \in \tau_2$. Now suppose the latter. Then there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $U = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m < n\}$. Then either $n =0$ or $0 < n$. Suppose $n =0$, then there are no natural number $< 0$, so $U = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m <n\} = \emptyset \in \tau_2$, so $U \in \tau_2$. Now suppose $0 < n$, then clearly $0 \in U = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m < n\}$. Thus $U \in \tau_2$.

Thus in any case $U \in \tau_2$. Thus, for every $U \in \tau_1, U \in \tau_2$, which is the definition of $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$.

Comment: okay, thank you!!!

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick remember to accept the answer if your question has been resolved,